# Gap on right hand side of body element with 100% width

Tags: html, css, overflow, responsive-design

I have a site at http://michaelscottweb.com which has 100% width containers and elements when the browser is above approx 450px. When you shrink the browser to below 980px and scroll to the right, there is a gap of around 20px on the body. This doesn't happen when you view the site above that resolution. Does anyone know what changes when to cause this?

[image]

css.

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    max-width:100%;
    -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background: #fff;
    color: #555;
    font-family: 'EBGaramondRegular';
    font-size: 15px;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine when I use the link you provide.

Comment: What a coincidense, i'm currently building dwightschruteonline.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's being caused by the google plus button, if you select all (command + a), you will see the outline on the google plus button sticking out to the right in the header.

Comment: It did, couldn't see the Iframes width initially, this showed it up nicely

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you fixed it. I was going to say you might need a css reset.

Comment: Sounds like fumigating your entire house for a single mosquito without being sure its the right pesticide